# Regular expression to match case insensitive string

Tags: regex, validation

We have a form in our website where at the very end the user has to type "SIGNED BY ME, [Name of the User]" in a text box before he or she can submit it. It is part of the requirement where the users has to digitally sign the form. The validation code for the text box is below:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="SIGNED BY ME, YOUR NAME" maxlength="500" value="" id="agreedment2_agreed_sign" name="agreedment2_agreed_sign" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please sign in the box" data-val-regex="SIGNED BY ME, @Model.Fullname.ToUpper()" data-val-regex-pattern="^signed by me, @Model.Fullname.ToLower()|SIGNED BY ME, @Model.Fullname.ToUpper()$">
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="agreedment2_agreed_sign" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

The jquery validation works fine if the user (say, John Smith) enters the text as "SIGNED BY ME, JOHN SMITH" or "signed by me, john smith". But it doesn't work if the user enters mixed case like "Signed by me, John Smith". I have tried adding modifier "/i" to the regex pattern which didn't work. I also tried adding data-val-regex-insensitive="true" to the input. It didn't work either.

Any suggestion, how I can achieve it.

Comment: Is the Regex used in C#? Then you'd do: `new Regex(<pattern>, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);`.

Comment: If you are only running the validation on the server side, you can use the inline modifier `(?i)`:  `data-val-regex-pattern="(?i)^(signed by me, @Model.Fullname.ToLower()|SIGNED BY ME, @Model.Fullname.ToUpper())$"` (also, use `EnableClientScript="False"` then to disable client side validation). See [this reference](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=25461&seqNum=4). An alterntive is to write your own CustomValidator. See [this post for hints](http://forums.asp.net/post/2248685.aspx).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I want the validation to work on the client side. Your suggestion doesn't work on the client side.

Comment: You can use XRegExp that allows `(?i)` in the pattern. However, you will need to add some code to handle the regex validation with that library.